# Apply expanding function on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a function that I wish to apply to a subsets of a pandas DataFrame, so that the function is calculated on all rows (until current row) from the same group - i.e. using a `groupby` and then `expanding`.

For example, this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {
        'group': ['A','A','A','B','B','B'],
        'time': [1,2,3,1,2,3],
        'x1': [10,40,30,100,200,300],
        'x2': [1,0,1,2,0,3]
                  }).sort_values('time')
```

i.e.

```
    group   time    x1      x2
0   A       1       10      1
3   B       1       100     2
1   A       2       40      2
4   B       2       200     0
2   A       3       30      1
5   B       3       300     3
```

and this function, for example:

```
def foo(_df):
    return _df['x1'].max() * _df['x2'].iloc[-1]
```

[Edited for clarity following feedback from jezrael: my actual function is more complicated, and cannot be easily broken down into components for this task. this simple function is just for an MCVE.]

I want to do something like:
`df['foo_result'] = df.groupby('group').expanding().apply(foo, raw=False)`

To obtain this result:

```
    group   time    x1  x2  foo_result
0   A       1       10  1   10
3   B       1       100 2   200
1   A       2       40  2   80
4   B       2       200 0   0
2   A       3       30  1   40
5   B       3       300 3   900
```

Problem is, running `df.groupby('group').expanding().apply(foo, raw=False)` results in `KeyError: 'x1'`.

Is there a correct way to run this, or is it not possible to do so in `pandas` without breaking down my function into components?

Comment: What do you mean by ```_df['x2'].iloc[-1]```? Previous row value of ```x2```? It doesn't seem like that from your expected output (it seems like you are taking current row there...)

Comment: `.iloc[-1]` is last row, not previous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An possible solution is to make the `expanding` part of the function, and use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
def foo1(_df):
    return _df['x1'].expanding().max() * _df['x2'].expanding().apply(lambda x: x[-1], raw=True)

df['foo_result'] = df.groupby('group').apply(foo1).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
print (df)
  group  time   x1  x2  foo_result
0     A     1   10   1        10.0
3     B     1  100   2       200.0
1     A     2   40   2        80.0
4     B     2  200   0         0.0
2     A     3   30   1        40.0
5     B     3  300   3       900.0
```

This is not a direct solution to the problem of applying a dataframe function to an `expanding` dataframe, but it achieves the same functionality.

Comment: Instead of the right side of multiplication- you can do: ```s = g['x1'].expanding().max() //
df['foo_result'] = s.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)*df['x2']```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this function was just something I made up for a minimal, reproducible example; Breaking down my actual function to its components this way is not what I need

Comment: @ItamarMushkin hmmm, I try answer for `Problem is, functions on .expanding() don't work on entire dataframe, only per column...
So, what can I do instead?`

Comment: I see... then my question was not clear enough. I've edited it following your feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Applying a dataframe function on an `expanding` window is apparently not possible (at least not for pandas version 0.23.0; EDITED - and also not 1.3.0), as one can see by plugging a `print` statement into the function.

Running `df.groupby('group').expanding().apply(lambda x: bool(print(x)) , raw=False)` on the given DataFrame (where the `bool` around the `print` is just to get a valid return value) returns:

```
0    1.0
dtype: float64
0    1.0
1    2.0
dtype: float64
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
dtype: float64
0    10.0
dtype: float64
0    10.0
1    40.0
dtype: float64
0    10.0
1    40.0
2    30.0
dtype: float64
```

(and so on - and also returns a dataframe with '0.0' in each cell, of course).

This shows that the `expanding` window works on a column-by-column basis (we see that first the expanding `time` series is printed, then `x1`, and so on), and does not really work on a dataframe - so a dataframe function can't be applied to it.

So, to get the obtained functionality, one would have to put the `expanding` inside the dataframe function, like in the accepted answer.